# Lync 2013 Microsoft Platform Ready Test fails - Wrong Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll

Tags: c#, ucma, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

I'm trying to pass a product through the Lync 2013 Platform Ready Test, but it's failing on this:

```
======================================================================
Log generated by MPR Lync 2013 Test Tool - Version 4.1.0.1 | (unsigned)
======================================================================
    Test name: Lync2013Test5
    Test date: 01/28/2014 16:08:34
    Tested on: Physical Machine
    Test for: Competency Test for Lync Server 2013
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 5 - Client is running in UI suppressed mode and the SDK version used is 15.0.4454.1509 or greater (Lync Client Tests).
======================================================================

01/28/2014 16:08:34 :: 
User selected the feature "Application uses UI Suppression".

UI Suppression is used by the application "<app>"

01/28/2014 16:08:34 :: 
The version of assembly Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll loaded by the application should be 15.0.4454.1509 or higher.
Current version of Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll loaded by application is: 
Test Status : Fail
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 5 - Client is running in UI suppressed mode and the SDK version used is 15.0.4454.1509 or greater (Lync Client Tests).
01/28/2014 16:08:34 End of Log.
======================================================================
```

However, I am actually referencing version 15.0.4535.1002, and can see that it has been loaded by my application.

I've also tried the WPF controls test and get the same thing.

Could anyone offer any help?

**UPDATE**

Just ran a sample project (provided with the SDK) through the tool and got this result:

```
======================================================================
Log generated by MPR Lync 2013 Test Tool - Version 4.1.0.1 | (unsigned)
======================================================================
    Test name: Lync2013Test8
    Test date: 01/30/2014 14:06:19
    Tested on: Physical Machine
    Test for: Competency Test for Lync Server 2013
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 3 - Determine if someone is using Lync SDK for client side application and the SDK version used is 15.0.4454.1509 or greater (Lync Client Tests).
======================================================================

01/30/2014 14:06:19 :: 
User selected the feature "Application uses WPF controls.".

01/30/2014 14:06:19 :: 
The version of assembly Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll loaded by the application should be 15.0.4454.1509 or higher.
Current version of Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll loaded by application is: 15.0.4535.1002
Test Status : Fail
======================================================================
Test case/Verification: TC 3 - Determine if someone is using Lync SDK for client side application and the SDK version used is 15.0.4454.1509 or greater (Lync Client Tests).
01/30/2014 14:06:19 End of Log.
======================================================================
```

I'm confused, is 15.0.4535.1002 not higher than 15.0.4454.1509...

Comment: I'm not familiar with that platform ready test, but do use Lync. The log line "Current version of Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll loaded by application is:" looks suspicious... I'd have expected there to be a version number after the colon, but its just a new line. Are you 100% sure the Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll is loading correctly?

Comment: I too found it suspicious so I ran a sample project provided by the SDK, even more confusing results were found, see above. Does anyone know the best way of reporting this issue to the relevant people?

Comment: For that update, was it a pre-compliled program or did you compile it. It might be as simple as the reference setup in the C# project file (the .csproj file). Can I suggest you manually edit that files for either your project (or the sample project) using Notepad.exe (etc.) and manually remove ALL references to Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll. Then using VS, add the reference back in using the Browse... button (making sure you pick the right version) rather than adding it from the list of .NET components found. It could be that it is pickup up the wrong version that way.